# Delete those comments that are automatically added when a user votes to close a question as duplicate, when the other question is deleted

Tags: feature-request, comments, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

On Drupal Answers, I have deleted a comment pointing to a question being duplicated because the question was already deleted from the OP.

> [image: screenshot]

I thought the comment was manually added from the user, but after looking at the timeline of the question, I discovered the comment was automatically added, since the user voted to close the question.

> [image: screenshot]

When the closing vote is cleared as in this case, the automatically added comment should be removed. Since the question is deleted, there is no reason for pointing the users to that question, since only 10K users can see it.

In the case the duplicated question is undeleted, the closing vote and the comments should be restored. The expiration time for the closing vote should not consider the period of time when the duplicated question was deleted, or should be reset when the duplicated question is undeleted; since what normally happens is that a user asks the same question twice in few time, I don't think there would be normally be much difference for the expiration time of the single closing vote.

Comment: how to be in cases when the other question is undeleted? If this happens, should the comment be restored as well?

Comment: If the comment is restored, then also the closing vote should be restored. It makes sense to restore them when the question is undeleted.

Comment: in the case of restoring close vote on un-deletion, what would be [meta-tag:expiration] rules?